# AngularJS ignoring stale XHR requests

Tags: ajax, angularjs

For some strange reason I can't find anything on what should be a trivial problem, well at least it is trivial in jQuery.

I have an autocomplete form, and I want to only show the data from the most recent XHR request.  I.E. If someone types in "Bec" and "Beck" that it will display the results for "Beck" even if the promise for "Bec" is fulfilled later.

I can't seem to intercept the XHR object and compare it to the XHR response as I can in jQuery.  Any ideas on how to best deal with this?

Comment: One thing to note, is that I need to pass the query into the $http request by reference.  This means that I cannot compare the input value on the callback to the current value as they will always match since the query has been set by reference.  I think I need to compare the XHR values by reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution.

```
    var _currentRequest = 0; 
    function _executeQuery() {
        _currentRequest++;
        var thisRequest = _currentRequest; //on callback compare these values
        }
```